How can I insert my variable into this line of SQL code or is there a better way to do this?
I am trying to take the country that the user inputs and check my database for said country, and find its corresponding country code. I will then take that country code and insert it into a different table. However i'm not sure where i'm going wrong in this particular line of code.
Here is the entire section of code that I am working with:
app.post('/add', async (req, res) => {
  let userInput = [];
  userInput.push(req.body.country);
  console.log(userInput);
  userInput.forEach((country) => {
    const result = db.query(`SELECT country_code FROM countries WHERE country_name = ${userInput}`, function (err, result) {
      db.query('INSERT INTO visited_countries (country_code) VALUES ($1)',     [data.result] );
    });
    console.log(result);
    if (userInput) {
      const countries = db.query('SELECT country_code FROM visited_countries');
      result.row.forEach((countries) => {
        countries.push(country.country_code);
      console.log(result.rows);
    });
    res.render('index.ejs', {countries: countries, total: countries.length});
    }
  });
});

This is the part I am trying to troubleshoot:
const result = db.query(`SELECT country_code FROM countries WHERE country_name = ${userInput}`

console.log(result) is returning undefined

why are you pushing the country in to array ? instead you can directly use country from body if you have multiple countries try to get country body param as an array

Don't format your user input into the query, use bind variables, like you did for the insert statement:
const result = 
    db.query('SELECT country_code FROM countries WHERE country_name = $1',
    [userInput],
    function (err, results) {
        // callback code...

